# django вывести значение из БД с ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

Добрый день. Нужно вывести из бд значения на страничку. Столкнулся с проблемой:
при выводе значение с полем ManyToManyField выдает такое: app.AuthUser.None, хотя поле не пустое...

модель:

```python
class AuthUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', message='Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30, validators=[alphanumeric])
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email field', unique=True, max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    # date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
    # profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads', blank=False, default='/static/selfphoto.jpg')
    user_bio = models.TextField()
    perm = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    podr = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    dolznost = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = AuthUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '%s %s %s' .format(self.last_name, self.first_name, self.second_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.second_name, self.podr, self.dolznost)

class Karto(models.Model):
    idname = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    small = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads', blank=True)
    soglas = models.ManyToManyField(AuthUser)
    madeby = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["idname"]
```

вьюха:

```
def docsupdocs(request, idname):
    args = {}
    args['perm'] = request.user.perm
    args['myq'] = Karto.objects.get(idname=idname)
    return render_to_response('self_docsupdocs.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

поле заполнял через админку:

```
class KartoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Karto
    fields = ['idname', 'small', 'file', 'datecreated', 'soglas', 'madeby']
    filter_horizontal = ['soglas',]
```

html:

```html
{% block owned %}

<p> allah </p>

{{ myq.small }}<br>
{{ myq.madeby }}<br>
{{ myq.datecreated }}<br><br>

{{ myq.soglas }}

{% endblock %}
```

результат:

```
allah

betta test
max
5 ноября 2015 г. 11:11

app.AuthUser.None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поле является отношением «многие-ко-многим», а значит по этим «многим» нужно пройтись, чтобы их вывести. Обычно это делается примерно так:

```
{% for user in myq.soglas.all %}
  {{ user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```